# Get Flickity instance from slider initialized in JS

Tags: javascript, flickity

I'm trying to access a Flickity instance with JS that has already been initialized in other JS code which I don't have access to. I have tried using `Flickity.data('.slider')`, as well as just creating a new Flickity instance with `new Flickity('.slider')`. `Flickity.data` returns `undefined`, and creating a new instance entirely returns a flickity object, but it doesn't actually correspond to the existing slider. I know neither of these approaches are *supposed* to work in this case, but is there any way to do this or is it not possible?